# How to fix fgets() hanging when reading popen()?

Tags: c, java-native-interface

I have been working on an Android app that does its functions in JNI. My problem is in a function where logcat displays until a button is pressed. I found where the problem occurs:

```
FILE *logcat = popen("su -c logcat threadtime", "r");

while (isRunning(running, env, thiz))
    if (fgets(&line, sizeof(line), logcat) != NULL) //<--- HERE
        appendLogWithToken(logger, line, env, thiz);
```

I have done some debugging and found out that the `fgets()` sleeps until another line is received. I have searched and found similar questions but no working answers. Are there any other functions that return null and don't wait for input, or is this fixable?

Comment: `fgets()` reads ('hangs') until it gets EOF (no more data and the write end of the pipe is closed) or until more data arrives — that's the design.  Is `logcat` exiting, or does it hang around in perpetuity?  If you want non-blocking I/O, you can use `fcntl()` on the underlying file descriptor to make the pipe non-blocking, but you need to know what you're about (`clearerr()` becomes a friend).  I'm suspicious that you have some design flaws, and/or you haven't thought things through carefully.  You don't show `pclose(logcat);`, for example — when do you close that file?

Comment: at first check logcat is opened or not with "if (logcat != NULL)"

Comment: It'll be dirty but I'd first use `fileno(3)` to get file descriptor, then call `select(2)` or `poll(2)` to check if there is any data. Then a non line-delimiter expecting read function like `read(2)` to actually read data.

Comment: This was only a part of the code. I don't have included all the function calls.

Comment: It *blocks* until another line is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonathan gave an excellent explanation as to why this occur.

A simple fix in your case is to use logcat -d.
Adding the -d option will send EOF at the end of the current buffer and allow fgets to continue (instead of the default option that monitors the buffer endleslly )